# Differentiation from first principles of fractional equation

Tags: derivatives

Bear with me folks, I'm only learning.

How do I differentiate $y=\frac{1}{x}$ from first principles? I get to:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{h}$

I then try to find a common denominator to subtract the terms in the numerator, but am then left with $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\frac{h}{x^2+xh}}{h}$ which always seems to reduce to zero (with $h$ tending to zero).

What's particularly frustrating is that I can easily find the answer ($-\frac{1}{x^2}$) using differentiation from rules. Any help enormously welcome.

Comment: It doesn’t tend to 0. Cancel the $h$ first.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for your help, but alas your answer is completely beyond me. Why doesn't h tend to zero? When should I cancel it?

Comment: You have two fraction bars. Do some simple algebra and rewrite it with only one fraction bar.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Okay I need to divide everything in my final expression by h, which is equivalent to multiplying everything by 1/h. But this makes every term in my expression a factor of h. If h tends to zero (which as far as I understand, it must, if the difference between the two points is to be infinitely small), then I am left with 0/0, that is, zero! I know I am making some ridiculously stupid mistake here, but I just can't see it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Figured it out - cancel out the hs before multiplying -h/h(x^2+xh) by 1/h. Avoids making everything a factor of h. I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is unsolvable if one reasons as follows, even though the reasoning is sound:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\frac{h}{x^2+xh}}{h}$

$\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{h}{x^2+xh}\div\frac{h}{1}$

$\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{h}{x^2+xh}\times\frac{1}{h}$

$\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{h}{h\left(x^2+xh\right)}$

The problem is that now everything is a factor of $h$ and so reduces to zero if $h$ tends to zero. Instead, one must reason as follows:

$\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{h}{x^2+xh}\times\frac{1}{h}$

Cancel out the $h$s to give:

$\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2+xh}\times\frac{1}{1}$

$\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2+xh}$

If $h$ tends to zero this gives:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: The first line of your post is misleading. The reasoning *is* sound and it *does* lead to the solution. You just have to keep going and have the presence of mind to cancel the $h$s

Comment: @FShrike Agreed; reasoning which leads indirectly to an answer by way of a wrong answer can be equally as sound as reasoning which leads directly to an answer.